# Calling a java class in a trigger on a view in an oracle database

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle10g

I created a view as:

```
CREATE or replace VIEW new_requests AS
 SELECT *
FROM new_requests@ECHOLDM
WHERE is_transfered=2
```

and a stored procedure through which i can call the my java code:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RL52.echo_LDM
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA 
  NAME 'src.com.echo.process.EchoLDMOrders.doIt()';
```

My trigger is as follows:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  LDM_trigger  
 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON  rl52.NEW_REQUESTS
 FOR EACH ROW
  CALL echo_LDM
  ;
```

Now whenever the view is updated nothing happens, so what am I missing here?

Comment: "whenever the view is updated" - are you actually inserting into the view; or are you expecting the trigger on the view to fire when an insert is performed directly on the underlying (remote in this case) table?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm expecting the trigger to fire whenever the view is updated depending on the underlying remote table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is really just a stored query. The underlying tables don't know the view exists, and changes to those don't affect the view directly. Next time you query the view the underlying tables are queried instead, and you see the data in the tables at that point.

An instead-of trigger is fired when you insert into the view, not when you insert into the base table. Usually this 'intercepts' the insert and modifies the base tables instead.

As a demo, using a local table (it being a remote table being accessed over a database link in your version doesn't make any difference to how this works):

```
create table t42 (id number);
create view v42 as select * from t42;
create trigger v42_trig instead of insert on v42 for each row
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Instead-of trigger fired for ID: ' || :new.id);
end;
/

set serveroutput on
```

If I insert into the view the trigger is fired, which we can see from the debug message:

```
insert into v42 (id) values (1);

1 row inserted.

Instead-of trigger fired for ID: 1
```

Because the trigger is *only* showing a message, no row was actually inserted in the base table, despite the status message returned (by SQL Developer in this case). Normally the trigger would do something more useful of course.

If I insert into the table directly, no debug is shown, because the trigger does not fire:

```
insert into t42 (id) values (2);

1 row inserted.
```

But that row was actually inserted, and querying the view only shows that - not the one intercepted by the trigger earlier:

```
select * from v42;

        ID
----------
         2
```

If you want some action to be taken when a row is inserted in the table then you have to have a trigger on the table itself. You could possibly replace your view with a local *materialized* view and have a trigger on that, but the database link rather complicated that too.

Comment: Alright I'll see what I can do with the remote tables, but thank you so much for your help.